# Neo4j interoperability between community and enterprise edition databases

Tags: neo4j, graphml, neo4j-java-api

I am having issue switching between neo4j enterprise and community versions.Since i was unable to do a graphml import,i switched to enterprise where i can import graphml databases.Once i am done i am trying to open the database file created in enterprise version in community version it is giving error.

```
  org.neo4j.server.database.LifeCycleManagingDatabase was succesfully initialized but failed to start
```

Is it possible to open a db created in enterprise version in community.What am i doing wrong here?

Please find the error i am getting when i am opening the db from java .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\roshni\graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:314)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:94)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:66)
at Testing.main(Testing.java:15)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@f1cb476' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:499)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:108)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:309)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@2ad13d80' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:499)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:108)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:493)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:532)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:493)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using? Does `data/graph.db/messages.log` show an stacktrace?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@776baf80' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception

Comment: the version is 2.3.0 for community version

Comment: neo4j enterprise version used is 2.1.8 for importing the graph.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to have same version of Neo4j community and enterprise.

If your enterprise version is older then community. I suggest to change following property for update datastore

**conf/neo4j.properties**

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @MicTech said, you cannot downgrade a datastore. Neo4j supports upgrades. So when moving from community to enterprise, the enterprise variant needs to be the same version *or* a newer one.

Before doing a store upgrade, it's crucial to do a clean shutdown with the old version.

Comment: Thanks @Mic Tech and stefan. i will try this and let you know.Also i am using neo4j jar files to access the db from my java program. Can i use the same jar file if the versions are same ?

Comment: using community 2.3.0-M01 and enterprise 2.3.0-m3 still not working getting the same error.

Comment: Is there any new neo4j jars vailable for 2.3.0-M-03

Comment: there is generally no upgrade path between milestones. Upgrades are only supported from one stable release to a subsequent one.

Answer (score 1):

As per their documentation on Ubuntu and Debian you can do an upgrade as follow, for **Neo4j 2.3.1**

The Neo4j Debian repository can be used on Debian or Ubuntu.

To use the repository follow these steps:

> wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo
>   apt-key add - echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/'
>   /tmp/neo4j.list sudo mv /tmp/neo4j.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
>   sudo apt-get update

Installing Neo4j
To install the latest Neo4j Community Edition:

> sudo apt-get install neo4j

To install the latest Neo4j Enterprise Edition:

> sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise

The installation process will guide you thru the upgrade